# Django regroup list

Tags: python, django

I have one problem with [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup) in Django.
The situation is: I have a dictionary by views.py, I need to do the following:

```
Box A_name:
1 section:
1.1 element 1
...
1.n element n

N section:
N.1 element
...
N.m element

Box B_name:
...
```

The code in html is:

```
{% load get_boxfilter %}
{% regroup all_boxes|dictsort:"box_type" by box_type as type %}

<ul>
{% for pos in type %}
    <li> Box {{ pos.grouper|get_boxfilter }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in pos.list %}

          <li> element {{ item.name }} section {{ item.section }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

get_boxfilter:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
from django import template
register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='get_groupfilter')
def get_boxfilter(value):
    gb_list = [u"NULL", u"A_name", u"B_name", u"N_name" ]
    return gb_list[int(value)]
```

Its pretty regroup by box-names:

```
Box A_name:
1. element 1 section 1
2. element 2 section 2
3. element 3 section 1
Box B_name:
...
```

but how to group by "section" (int values)?

```
Box A_name:
1 section:
1.1 element 1
1.2 element 3
2 section:
2.1 element 2
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you also post dictionary contents. It will help to give you accurate answer. Thanks

Comment: 'id', 'name', 'section', 'box_type'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't just regroup by section?

```
{% load get_boxfilter %}
{% regroup all_boxes by section as type %}

<ul>
{% for pos in type %}
    <li> Box {{ pos.type|get_boxfilter }}
    <ol style="list-style-type: decimal">
         <li>{{ pos.grouper }}</li>
         <ol style="list-style-type: decimal">
             {% for item in pos.list %}
                 <li> element {{ item.name }}</li>
             {% endfor %}
         </ol>
    </ol>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: I have not tested it. Please test and let me know if any issue.

Comment: Also not sure if regroup by type is required any more. Depends on your requirements.

Comment: value error at `<li> Box {{ pos.type|get_boxfilter }}`: invalid literal for int() with base 10.

Comment: I assume that error is raise from `get_boxfilter`. Can you check what value the filter is receiving by printing `print value` at start of function.

Comment: why there is a need for `get_boxfilter` even. Please try to test my code without using the filter.

Comment: without filter it works, there is more elements. And I need to group them by box names